# How to check markup after I get page data in OnInitializedAsync method?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, bunit

I'm new to Blazor and bUnit. I have component that renders an edit form and I get the values for the form in my OnInitializedAsync event.

I'm having trouble working out how to use cut.WaitForState() or cut.WaitForAssertion().

Here's my razor code:

```
@page "/{AppId:guid}/app-settings-edit"
<section class="app-settings-edit">
    <h1 class="page-title">Application Settings</h1>
    @if (InitializedComplete)
    {
        <p>Hello World</p>
        ...
```

And my code behind:

```
public partial class AppSettingsEdit
{
    protected bool InitializedComplete;

    [Parameter]
    public Guid AppId { get; set; }

    [ValidateComplexType]
    public AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; } = new AppSettings();

    [Inject]
    public IAppSettingsDataService AppSettingsDataService { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AppSettings = await AppSettingsDataService.Get(AppId);
        InitializedComplete = true;
    }
    ...
```

And here's my Test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void MyFact()
    {
        Services.AddSingleton<IAppSettingsDataService, MockAppSettingsDataService>(x => new MockAppSettingsDataService(x.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>()));

        var cut = RenderComponent<AppSettingsEdit>(parameters => parameters
            .Add(p => p.AppId, Guid.Parse("55E5097B-B56A-40D7-8A02-A5B94AAAD6E1"))
        );

        Assert.NotNull(cut.Instance.AppSettingsDataService);

        cut.WaitForState(() => cut.Find("p").TextContent == "Hello World", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        cut.MarkupMatches("<p>Hello World</p>");
    }
```

When I debug the test, I can see the OnInitializedAsync firing, however my markup never changes to include 'Hello World' and the WaitForState() command fails.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the task returned from your `AppSettingsDataService.Get()` method ever completes?

I would make sure that the task returned from `AppSettingsDataService.Get()` is already completed, otherwise you need to a way to complete the task after the component is rendered. There are many ways to do this, it all depends on how your mock is implemented.

As for your `WaitFor`, you can just use the `WaitForAssertion` method in this case, i.e.: `cut.WaitForAssertion(() => cut.MarkupMatches("<p>Hello World</p>"));`

**A little background:**
The `WaitFor*` methods are used when the component under test is being rendered asynchronously, since the test, running in a different thread, doesn't know when that will happen.

In general, you should never need to set a custom timeout, the default is 1 second, but the `WaitFor*` methods will retry the assertion/predicate every time a renderer happens. Its only when the thing that triggers the rendering will take more than one second, e.g. if you are using bUnit to perform end-2-end testing and e.g. pulling data from a real web service.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes, the AppSettingsDataService.Get() method completes. I've placed breakpoints in the OnInitializedAsync method and can inpect the returned object.
I can also see the InitializedComplete value change to true. 
Does bUnit monitor the OnInitializedAsync Task? And if so, does bUnit then perform a Render?
When I debug the test, I can see that the OnInitializedAsync method completes, however Test method code running after this point does not detect a change in the markup. Should it?

Comment: Whoops, I left the TimeSpan code in. I thought I took that out..

Comment: When OnInitislized completes, it should cause the component to rerender. If the awaited services returns a completed task immediately, then you shouldn't even need to use WaitForXxx.

Comment: WaitFor does not know when your task itself completes, but it does know whenever a component renders, for whatever reason. You can try to force the issue by calling StateHasChanged.

Comment: I'm not seeing the component rerender after OnInitialized completes. Should I be able to see the change in the markup when i loop? 
    var markup = cut.Markup;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                markup = cut.Markup;
            }

Comment: I would not use Thread.Sleep. I would instead just add an `await Task.Delay(100);` or similar before looking at the markup. Feel free to drop by https://github.com/egil/bUnit/discussions and add your question there with a sample project that reproduces the problem, then I can better help debug.